# Dropzone.js and symfony formbuilder

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, formbuilder

I'm trying to handle dropzone.js to work correct with my entity symfony formbuilder.

Everything works properly if I'm using simple `<input type="file" id="form_file" name="form[file]">`

BUT if I'm using dropzone.js I get this difference in my POST:
[image: difference in POST]

How I can handle it?

This is my js for it:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { 
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                parallelUploads: 25,
                maxFiles: 25,

                init: function() {
                    var myDropzone = this;

                    $("#submit-all").click(function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                myDropzone.processQueue();
                            }
                    );

                }

            }
```

My form file looks like:

```
    <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="wizard-big dropzone" action="{{ path('add') }}" method="post"  {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' } }) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
        <div class="fallback"> 
         {{ form_widget(form.file, {'attr': { 'class': 'cotam' } }) }}
        </div>
        </div>
<button type="submit" id="submit-all" class="btn">Upload the file</button>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </form>
```

And my controller:

```
public function addAction(Request $Request) {

        $photo = new Photo();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($photo)
            ->add('name')
            ->add('file')
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($Request);

        if ($form->isValid() && $Request->isMethod('POST')) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($photo);
            $em->flush();

            $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('add'));
        }



        return $this->render('MyBundle::add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Could You help me?

Comment: Have you tried setting of `uploadMultiple` to false?

Comment: When I set i up  I have: `files] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object
        (
            [parameters:protected] => Array
                (
                    [file] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
                        ....` But I would like to get `[files] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object
        (
            [parameters:protected] => Array
             [form] => Array
                 (
                     [file] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object                         ....
`

Comment: I think I need to connect it somehow with formbuilder, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found the answer... It was simple as possible..

You need to just add a option:

`paramName: "form[file]"`

To Your dropzone configuration.